# Iterate enum values using values() and valueOf in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Am a newbie here. Can anyone give an example to iterate an enum with values and valueOf methods??

This is my enum class

```
enum class Gender {
    Female,
    Male
}
```

I know we can get the value like this

```
Gender.Female
```

But I want to iterate and display all the values of Gender. How can we achieve this? Anyhelp could be appreciated

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can use [`values`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html#working-with-enum-constants) like so:

```
val genders = Gender.values()
```

Since Kotlin 1.1 there are also helper methods available:

```
val genders = enumValues<Gender>()
```

With the above you can easily iterate over all values:

```
enumValues<Gender>().forEach { println(it.name) }
```

To map enum name to enum value use `valueOf`/[`enumValueOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/enum-value-of.html) like so:

```
 val male = Gender.valueOf("Male")
 val female = enumValueOf<Gender>("Female")
```

Comment: What is the order of iteration (by abc of `name`, or `ordinal`,...)? Is this method stable (iteration order doesn't change if enum order and items don't change)?

Comment: See [this Kotlin issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-48872) aiming to replace `Enum.values()` with a more modern and performant alternative.

Answer (score 19):

You're getting `[LGender;@2f0e140b` or similar as the output of printing `Gender.values()` because you're printing the array reference itself, and arrays don't have a nice default `toString` implementation like lists do.

The easiest way to print all values is to iterate over that array, like this:

```
Gender.values().forEach { println(it) }
```

Or if you like method references:

```
Gender.values().forEach(::println)
```

You could also use [`joinToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) from the standard library to display all values in a single, formatted string (it even has options for prefix, postfix, separator, etc):

```
println(Gender.values().joinToString()) // Female, Male
```

Answer (score 14):

You can add this method to your enum class.

```
fun getList(): List<String> {
    return values().map {
        it.toString()
    }
}
```

And call

```
val genders = Gender.getList()
// genders is now a List of string
// Female, Male
```

Comment: I was only able to get this to work if I added the method to the enum class' companion object. If you add the method directly to the enum class, you can only access it with Gender.Female.getList().

Answer (score 4):

You can do this and get a new array of your enum type `Gender`

```
val arr = enumValues<Gender>()
```

and if you want a list of its, you can use the extension. `toList()`

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin **1.9.0**, the `entries` property is introduced as a replacement for the `values()` function

> The `entries` property returns a pre-allocated immutable list of your enum constants. This is particularly useful when you are working with collections and can help you avoid performance issues.

```
enum class Gender {
    Female,
    Male
}

for (gender in Gender.entries) println(gender.toString())
```

#### Reference

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/enum-classes.html#working-with-enum-constants