# Convert Enum.values() to Array<String> with a generic function in Kotlin

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin, enums

In Java it would be like this

```
public static String[] getNames(Class<? extends Enum<?>> e) {
    return Arrays.stream(e.getEnumConstants()).map(Enum::name).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

How might I change this code to Kotlin

Thanks... Newbie to Kotlin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rather literal translation would be:

```
fun getNames(e: Class<out Enum<*>>) =
    Arrays.stream(e.enumConstants).map(Enum<*>::name).toArray<String>(::arrayOfNulls)
```

This gives you an `Array<String?>`.

However, I think a more kotlin-y way to do this would be to return a `List<String>`, since that is what the built-in [`Array.map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) extension function returns. You should also write this as an extension function/property on `KClass<out Enum<*>>`, rather than the Java `Class`.

```
fun KClass<out Enum<*>>.enumConstantNames() =
    this.java.enumConstants.map(Enum<*>::name)
    // if you really want an Array<String> for some reason, you can add
    // .toTypedArray()
    // but I don't see any reason to
```

Usage:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(Foo::class.enumConstantNames()) // [A, B, C]
}

enum class Foo {
    A, B, C
}
```

Comment: How would you go about modifying this great solution. If you would like the list output to be the values of the values.
So instead of A, B, C outputing A.a, B.b, C.c if you know what I mean?

Comment: @EmmanuelConradie I don't know what you mean. Where did `A.a`, `B.b` and `C.c` come from? What are the "values of the values"?

Comment: enum class Foo(val value: String) {
   A("a"), B("b"), C("c")
}
Sorry I meant to say Foo.A.value

Comment: @EmmanuelConradie Well then the extension would only work on `Foo`, so `fun KClass<Foo>.enumConstantNames() = this.java.enumConstants.map { "${it.name}.${it.value}" }`. If you have more questions about this, you should post a new question with more details. This doesn't seem related to your original question anymore.

Comment: Great thank you, I will post a new question next time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enumValues<T>()` as shown in [Working with enum constants](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/enum-classes.html#working-with-enum-constants)
and `map` the names.

```
enum class RGB { RED, GREEN, BLUE }

inline fun <reified T : Enum<T>> getNames() = enumValues<T>().map { it.name }

val namesList = getNames<RGB>() // [RED, GREEN, BLUE]
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this official documentation of Kotlin for detailed information.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/enum-classes.html

Kotlin enum can be written in the following way:

```
enum class Direction {
    NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST
}
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/java.util.-enumeration/to-list.html

This is a sample to use existing Java Enum to Kotlin list.

```
val numbers = java.util.Hashtable<String, Int>()
numbers.put("one", 1)
numbers.put("two", 2)
numbers.put("three", 3)

// when you have an Enumeration from some old code
val enumeration: java.util.Enumeration<Int> = numbers.elements()

// you can convert it to list and transform further with list operations
val list = enumeration.toList().sorted()
println(list) // [1, 2, 3]
```

Also this answer might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44300496/4491971