# How to loop through Seal Class object without Reflection?

Tags: kotlin

I try to loop through my seal class of

```
sealed class NavigationItem(val route: String, val icon: Int, val title: String, val color: String) {
    object Home : NavigationItem("home", R.drawable.ic_home, "Home", "#FFFF00")
    object Music : NavigationItem("music", R.drawable.ic_music, "Music", "#FF00FF")
    object Movies : NavigationItem("movies", R.drawable.ic_movie, "Movies", "#00FFFF")
    object Books : NavigationItem("books", R.drawable.ic_book, "Books", "#FFAAAA")
    object Profile : NavigationItem("profile", R.drawable.ic_profile, "Profile", "#AAAAFF")
}
```

Using the below

```
 NavigationItem::class.sealedSubclasses.forEach {
            it.objectInstance?.apply {
                // Do something with each of the object (this)
            }
}
```

However, it complaints

```
kotlin.jvm.KotlinReflectionNotSupportedError: Kotlin reflection implementation is not found at runtime. Make sure you have kotlin-reflect.jar in the classpath
```

I want to avoid using Reflection to loop through them, is that possible? Or I have to use Enum for that purpose?

Comment: Given that all subclasses are `object`s, can you use `enum class` instead of `sealed class` ?

Comment: Why are you trying to use objects to do this in the first place?

Comment: AFAIK, if you want to loop over subclasses of a sealed class it can only be done via reflection. If you need to just store different constant values for `val route: String, val icon: Int, val title: String, val color: String` and use them uniquely, an `enum class` itself is a better fit.

Comment: In this case, I can switch to enum. I'm here to see if I can loop through objects in seal classes (I know the example above doesn't reflect the best the use of seal class, but just as a simple sample).  Thanks @MadhuBhat for the pointer and affirming my understanding

Comment: You probably want to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300410/iterate-enum-values-using-values-and-valueof-in-kotlin

Comment: The exception you're getting suggests you forgot to import the Kotlin reflection dependency: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#jvm-dependency

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try with Enum values() or you must import kotlin-reflection library to your project.

Put this into your dependencies.

`impolementation org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${Versions.kotlin}`

And it will work properly.

One problem of this can be the order of sealedSubclasses. But there are many ways to implement this.

one thing I tried is all the Subclasses have index value and then sort it at the end or you can use mapIndexed pipeline or something.