# (Kotlin) Convert Enum to List of String

Tags: kotlin, graphql

I have a graphql schema file in which I define an enum:

```
enum Job {
    OPEN,

    PAUSED,

    CLOSED
}
```

I then have a query resolver written in kotlin for my filters like so:

```
input.Job?.let { FindJobFilter(JobField.JOB, it) }
```

The `it` in question is requires a `List<String>` but I am supplying it a (Mutable)`List<Job!>`.

I am trying to write a helper function so that I can convert the `it` to the expected type of `List<String>` but can't seem to figure it out .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate enum values using values() and valueOf in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300410/iterate-enum-values-using-values-and-valueof-in-kotlin)

Comment: Naming nitpick: unless you're using the word ‘job’ in a very unusual way, CLOSED and the others are not jobs — they're job _statuses_. (It's not easy finding the right names for things, but it saves _lots_ of problems down the line, both for anyone else who works on the code, and also for you in months and years to come.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to map the list of Jobs to their names:

```
input.Job?.let { FindJobFilter(JobField.JOB, it.map { it?.name }) }
```